# Wifi not working on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, wifi

I installed Fedora 23 32-bit on my DELL latitude E5500, everything went well -I guess- but my wifi is not activated and the indicator is not lit up, I checked the manual switch and it's on -so is my Bluetooth- but still no wifi

this is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
02:01.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev ba)
02:01.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
02:01.2 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 21)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761e Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

Comment: Read through the output of `lspci` for something that relates to Wireless or Network and post the line in your question - it'll give people a better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: The last line of the lspci output is your Network controller, which means that it has at least been detected. What is the output of 'iwconfig' and  'ip a'?

Comment: Broadcom does not redistribute the driver for this card in a way which allows us (Fedora) to legally redistribute. I don't think the situation has changed since Fedora 18, unfortunately.

Comment: I went through the Question that mattdm linked, but still find it pretty hard to understand what OP is supposed to do. Am i getting it right that a non-free driver is needed that can not be shipped with fedora because of license issues? If so, could someone provide the OP with a link or even better with an explanation on how to install the driver? In the linked question it was only mentioned that this guy solved it by using a different kernel that included the driver. I don't use Fedora and thus can't provide an explanation on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Fedora, and thus my answer might be faulty, especially anything that is yum-related. Please correct me if this is the case. You seem to be missing a driver that (because the manufacturer of your wireless chipset does not allow that) can not be included in fedora by default. It can however be installed using yum. To do so, connect the pc to the internet using a cable, and run the following commands:

```
yum search kmod-wl
yum update
yum install kmod-wl
```

Reboot, and your wifi card should work. [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-linux-install-broadcom-wl-sta-wireless-driver-for-bcm43228/)
is where i found the info, it is meant for Fedora 20 but probably still up-to-date. The explanation also covers how to connect to a network after getting the card to work.